# Silverlight: Is creating multiple instances of the same Silverlight object in one HTML page acceptable?

Tags: silverlight, multiple-instances

in our corporate directory users can search for their coworkers. Results are then displayed in a table-like layout on a plain HTML page (the backend is PHP if that's any matter). The list is limited to 25 entries.

Now the request has come up to show the presence status from Microsoft Lync next to every entry in that list. Creating a tiny Silverlight application to represent the status of one single person is quite easy, placing it to the left of each name is also.

This way of doing it will of course result in up to 25 almost-identical Silverlight objects beeing created and then accessing the Lync client API.

Another way to do it would be to place the complete listing inside a (more complex) Silverlight application, so that there wouldn't be but one instance on the page. This would also cause quite some extra development work.

The question: Is it considered bad practice to create 25 instances of the same Silverlight object on one single web page?

Thanks for any input or opinion you can give,

Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using this in an internal corporate environment and getting the finished product out quickly is important then you're likely fine.  Each Silverlight object will need to query the Lync status of each employee so that may be a deciding factor in terms of performance.

Alternatively, it wouldn't be all the difficult or labor intensive to create a simple single  user control representing a single user's Lync status and then display all inside of a single Silverlight app.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Besides getting it out quickly it is also important not to change the users experience to heavily. I think we'll go for the "multi-object" solution and will probably start a new version of the directory in parallel so that the users can decide for their own which one to use. This should allow for a soft migration.